# Tomcat ClassPath Not Working For Javac Compilation

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to compile a servlet on my tomcat classpath and it will not work even though I believe I have the right command. I want to use json utils for parsing and the obvious servlets api. However, I cannot get the package to be ever found. I reinstalled java, which is java 11, and I also reinstalled Tomcat, which is Tomcat 10. This is on a Windows machine.

This is what I do in the console and what gets outputted.

```
 D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.0.2\webapps\helloservlet\WEB-INF>javac -cp 
   ".;D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.0.2/lib/servlet-api.jar;D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat- 
  10.0.2/lib/tomcat-util.jar;.;" -d classes src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java -source 
   1.8 -target 1.8

  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
  src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
  public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
                                  ^
  symbol: class HttpServlet
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                     ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class HelloServlet
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class HelloServlet
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
               throws IOException, ServletException {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class HelloServlet
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:4: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:6: error: package org.apache.json.util does not exist
import org.apache.json.util.*;
^
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:10: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
   @Override
   ^
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
          JSONObject j = new JSONObject(request);
          ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class HelloServlet
src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
          JSONObject j = new JSONObject(request);
                             ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class HelloServlet
10 errors
1 warning
```

Comment: Is it `javax.servlet.HttpServlet` or `jakarta.servlet.HttpServlet`? Tomcat 10 conforms to the Servlet 5.0 API, so it only has the latter. Tomcat 9 (Servlet 4.0) uses the former.

Comment: Ah! That fixed my problem with servlets! Maybe my import for utils is wrong as well. I didn't realize it had changed after using a new tomcat version.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz does Tomcat 10 have a json parser? When I import org.apache.tomcat.util.json, it does not work. But using * works and the JSONObject just doesnt work.

Comment: No, you need to add the JSON parser yourself to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.